# React Router Link taking user to blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a nested react router route where the nested route is defined in a separate component from the main router switch.  I created a link in one of the nested route’s components that will take a user to a page/component in the main router switch.  However, when clicking on this link, the url displays correctly, but I get a blank page.  It is only when I hit the refresh button that the page displays correctly.  How do I get the page to display correctly without hitting refresh?  Funny thing is when I use a  and set the href to the page, the link works correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: I think about 9 times out of 10 when I see this happen it's because more than 1 router is being used. We can't tell though because you've not included any code in your question. We can't help debug code we can't see. Please update your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You provided the answer.  I have an additional router listed.  Thank you!

Comment: No worries, it happens. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an invalid URL. Try adding a 404 page and see if that's what you get instead.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match

Short of that, it might be a problem with what components you are trying to render.

Answer (score 0):

I had an additional router listed in one of the components.  Once I got rid of that, everything worked.